# strange html file returned by web server

Tags: tracking, httpresponse, web-crawler, optimization

While working on a web crawler, I ran across this strange occurrence; the following is a snippet of the page content returned by the web server for http://nexgen.ae :

```
< ! D O C T Y P E   H T M L   P U B L I C   " - / / W 3 C / / D T D   H T M L   4 . 0   T r a n s i t i o n a l / / E N " > 

 < H T M L > < H E A D > < T I T L E > N e x G e n   T e c h n o l o g i e s   L L C |   F i n g e r p r i n t   T i m e   A t t e n d a n c e   M a n a g e m e n t   S y s t e m |   A c c e s s   C o n t r o l   M a n a g e m e n t   S y s t e m |   F a c e   R e c o g n i t i o n |   D o o r   A c c e s s   C o n t r o l |   E m p l o y e e s   A t t e n d a n c e |   S o l u t i o n   P r o v i d e r |   N e t w o r k   S t r u c t u e d   C a b l i n g | D u b a i |   U A E ) < / T I T L E >
```

As you can see, the web server seems to have inserted a space character after every other character in the original HTML source. I checked the HTML source with "Page Source" in Firefox and there were no extra spaces there. I also checked other web pages from the same website, and I am obtaining the correct HTML file for those pages.  So far the problem seems to only be happening with this website's default page when accessed through a web crawler.

I noticed the html file contains "google optimizer tracking script" at the very end. I wonder if the problem has anything to do with that...

Or could this just be the Website manager's way of keeping web crawlers away?   If that's the case, a robots.txt file would do!

Answer (score 1):

Those probably aren't spaces, they are null bytes. The page is encoded in UTF-16 (multiples of 2 bytes per character, minimum 2), and because the website has not properly specified its encoding in its HTTP headers, you are trying to read it as ASCII (1 byte per character) or possibly UTF-8 (1 byte or more per character).

To see what I mean, open it in your browser and change the encoding (somewhere in the browser's menus, might have to right-click on the page) and choose the UTF-16LE option.